# What could be the casual version of this expression?

Tags: grammar, translation

ご存じの通り

知りのように
知りの通り
Are those correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「知りのように」「知りの通り」 would be incorrect. I would say:

> 「知っての通り」
>   「知っている通り」
>   「｛あなたも/XXさんもetc｝知っているように」
>   「｛あなたも/XXさんもetc｝知る通り」

Comment: 知っている通り or 知っているの通り?

Comment: @user27223 「知っている通り」です。「知っている**の**通り」とは言いません・・・